# Using Chebyshev polynomials in wavetables

Tags: audio

How are Chebyshev polynomials used in wavetables for audio synthesis? I dont understand how to store these inside wavetables?

How does the synthesized audio result in matching to the correct index in the wavetable and what part of the Chebyshev polynomials are actually stored in the wavetable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chebyshev polynomials are mainly used for [waveshaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveshaper), where an input signal is distorted by applying a memory-less non-linear function to it. This shaping function is stored in a look-up table (wavetable). If you use Chebyshev polynomials, then the polynomial just defines the shaping function, and the wavetable is generated just like for any other shaping function.

If the output is given by $y=f(x)$, where $x$ is the input, then the wavetable contains values $y$ for a given range of input values $x$. The function $f(x)$ can be defined in any desired way, and one way to define it is to use Chebyshev polynomials, which for a pure sinusoidal input generate a given harmonic.

Comment: Thanks. "a given range of input values x" - so in a practical synthesizer, there will be hundreds of wavetables across the octaves? or could the input value be transformed into the wavetable range and then the output transformed back to the output range?

Comment: @Helium3: By "range" I meant the range of input values (minimum and maximum signal values), not the frequency range.

Comment: That's the part I dont understand. So if the values are floating point -1.0 - 1.0, and the wavetable is indexed using this to return a filtered value, is the function generic and independent of the frequency? And for each higher order polynomial function there is a related wavetable? The problem I guess is interpolation then as there are infinite values in that range. How is the interpolation linked to the polynomial?

Comment: @Helium3: You just have a function $y=f(x)$ where $x$ is the input signal value; this is totally independent of frequency. For each function $f(x)$ that you want to implement, you generally need a separate wavetable. For indexing the wavetable you can either quantize the input values $x$, or you use linear interpolation between the two closest wavetable entries.